# Why not leave ' shouldRasterize' on?

Tags: core-animation

Why people usually switch the status of `shouldRasterize` instead of leave it on?

I can assume this is relevant to resource consumption but can anybody explain me some detail or provide some relevant link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have it backwards here. The default is to have it off, and that's typically the correct setting (which is why it's the default). In some cases it can improve performance to cache a rasterized bitmap, but it can also be slower, particularly if the layer contents change often and you don't get to use the cache many times.

Rasterizing interferes with some kinds of composition and antialiasing, so it can reduce quality, and definitely can impact magnification transforms. Sometimes its used in complex animations where performance is more important than quality, and sometimes to dodge subpixel anti-aliasing artifacts in animations. But again, you should be turning it on in order to address an issue that you're actually seeing. (Some old antialiasing tricks don't even make sense anymore now that Retina displays are the norm. Never just copy a trick someone says "fixes stuff" without verifying that it actually does.)

`shouldRasterize` is something to experiment with if you have a significant rendering bottleneck because it can help in some cases, but must always be explored in conjunction with data from the Core Animation tools in Instruments. It can provide pretty dramatic improvements on layers that have shadows (but it can also interfere with the shadow's appearance if it needs to be drawn over different backgrounds). But it certainly isn't something you should use routinely. If it were a magic "go fast" option, then it would be the default. Most of the time, iOS is going to do the right thing on its own.